# How to insert commas in numbers in an html template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an html template, I want to make a generalize function that itself finds all the numbers in my template and insert comma after every 3 digits. Currently I am using this function which may take some value as an input to convert it into comma separated form.

```
function commafy( num ) {
    var str = num.toString().split('.');
    if (str[0].length >= 5) {
        str[0] = str[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
    }
    if (str[1] && str[1].length >= 5) {
        str[1] = str[1].replace(/(\d{3})/g, '$1 ');
    }
    return str.join('.');
}
```

My template contains labels, tables & input fields.
Please help me how can I do that?

Comment: could you be more specific what your html markup would look like so it would be easy to  suggest solution to your problem

Answer (score 1):

1. If the templates know where the numbers are, just put a class for them. After the template being rendered, select and change the numbers together. Note: there'is a jquery plugin called [format_currency](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/).
2. If the templates does NOT know, do it after render done:

   ```
   $('#TEMPLATE_CONTAINER input,#TEMPLATE_CONTAINER label,#TEMPLATE_CONTAINER td').each(function(){          
       FORMAT($(this));//format only if $(this).text() is a number     
   })
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/P3CSF/

you can use this awesome function for number formatting

e.g

```
var num=123456789.12345
num.formatMoney(5) //returns 123,456,789.12345 
num.formatMoney(2) //returns 123,456,789.12
```

function code is here :-

```
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
var n = this, 
    c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
    d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
    t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
    s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
    i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", 
    j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
   return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
 };

console.log((123456789.12345).formatMoney(5, '.', ','));
console.log((123456789.12345).formatMoney(2));
```

if you want plugins :- [Plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-currencyprice-plugins)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways:

1. You can wrap your money values inside a `<span class='money'></span>` span, and then using jQuery format those values, on `DOM ready`.
2. Using Angular JS, you can give your money values a directive, say `ng-money` and define that directive such that it formats the content of that span.
3. Third way is to send money values already commified (as you mentioned that :D ), and use them directly inside your template. Usually on server side, it's easier to format numbers and values.

Answer (score 0):

I've a solution which probably works the way you want. This is only as far my understanding of the problem.

Here are few lines of code. The fiddle is also [linked](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/UY4W8/)

```
var formatedNumbers=function(){
    count=document.getElementsByTagName('input').length;

    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        if(!isNaN(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value) && document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value!=""){
            document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value=formatNumber(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: this fails for zeros - try entering 1000000